# How to get the name of a temporary file created by File.tmpfile in D2?

Tags: file-io, d

I need to generate a temporary file, fill it with some data and feed it to an external program. Based on description of D available [here](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#tmpfile) I'm using `File.tmpfile()` method:

```
auto f = File.tmpfile();
writeln(f.name());
```

which doesn't provide a way to get the generated file name. It's documented that `name` might be empty. In Python I would do that like this:

```
(o_fd, o_filename) = tempfile.mkstemp('.my.own.suffix')
```

Is there a simple, safe and cross-platform way to do that in D2?

Answer (score 0):

Due to how `tmpfile()` works, if you need the name of the file you can't use it. However, I have already created a module to work with temporary files. It uses conditional compilation to decide on the method of finding the temporary directory. On windows, it uses the %TMP% environment variable. On Posix, it uses /tmp/.

This code is licensed under the WTFPL, so you can do whatever you want with it.

```
module TemporaryFiles;
import std.conv,
       std.random,
       std.stdio;

version(Windows) {
    import std.process;
}

private static Random rand;

/// Returns a file with the specified filename and permissions
public File getTempFile(string filename, string permissions) {
    string path;
    version(Windows) {
        path = getenv("TMP") ~ '\\';
    } else version(Posix) {
        path = "/tmp/";
        // path = "/var/tmp/"; // Uncomment to survive reboots
    }
    return File(path~filename, permissions);
}

/// Returns a file opened for writing, which the specified filename
public File getTempFile(string filename) {
    return getTempFile(filename, "w");
}

/// Returns a file opened for writing, with a randomly generated filename
public File getTempFile() {
    string filename = to!string(uniform(1L, 1000000000L, rand)) ~ ".tmp";
    return getTempFile(filename, "w");
}
```

To use this, simply call getTempFile() with whatever arguments you want. Defaults to write permission.

As a note, the "randomly generated filenames" aren't truely random, as the seed is set at compile time.